# Use FOR Loop inside END block of awk command

Tags: awk

I'm trying to find the average number of files per day.

The following script works:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -l | grep "^-" | awk '{
key=$6$7
freq[key]++
}
END {
for (date in freq)
               printf "%s\t%d\n", date, freq[date]
}'
```

When I add do and done for the for loop like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -l | grep "^-" | awk '{
key=$6$7
freq[key]++
}
END {
for (date in freq)
do
               printf "%s\t%d\n", date, freq[date]
done
}'
```

I get the below error:

```
awk: cmd. line:8: done
awk: cmd. line:8: ^ syntax error
```

How to write multi-line for loop statements inside END block of awk command?

**Solution:**

We need to use { and } to start and end for loop in END block of awk command.

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -l | grep "^-" | awk '{
key=$6$7
freq[key]++
}
END {
for (date in freq)
{
        count=count+1
        total=total+freq[date];
        printf "%s\t%d\n", date, freq[date]
}
printf "Average files per day : %d\n",(total/count)
}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `done` in `awk` syntax at all, and `do` just as `do statement while (condition)`.

You need curly brackets instead:

```
for (date in freq) { cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider that, in general, parsing `ls` output is problematic.

See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (plus linked pages).

As a solution for manipulating date/time of files, you can use GNU `find` (where available) and use GNU extesion like `-printf "%T@"` to get [unix epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or output time in easy parsable format. (check `man find` or [read it here](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Time-Directives)
 ).

--EDIT: Kevin point out this :

BSD `find` (and other implementations) do not have this functionality. But it's possible to use `stat` (where present) to obtain the same informations. Check man.

--EDIT END

As example you can do samething like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%TY%Tm%Td-%TH%TM%TS"
```

to obtain modification times in `YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS` format.

Comment: BSD `find` does *not* have anything equivalent to `-printf`, the only way to get it to print time is `-ls`, and then you need to parse that.

Comment: Or, using external utils, `find . -type f -exec stat -f '%Sm' {} +`

Comment: @ Kevin : I do not undestand your remark: using external utility like `find` is exactly what I'm trying to suggest. But not all `find` utility on different *nix have this feature.

Comment: Your post seemed to imply that BSD find had some functionality more or less equivalent to printf, I was pointing out it doesn't. By "external utility" I was referring to `stat`, external to `find`.

Comment: @ Kevin : Ok, understood, it is not in BSD find. I'll edit and attribute.

Comment: It's not that much that `BSD` `find` doesn't have `-printf`, but more than only `GNU` `find` has it. None of the other `find` implementations (`BSD` or other) have it.